# MS Access 2007 : the code vba not running

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

i need a help please

in example , i write code vba for button close

```
Private Sub Commande15_Click()
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Login"
End Sub
```

the code is correct but does not running ! any code i write it not running

heeeeeeelp plzzz

Comment: did you rename that button ? (or the form)

Comment: No , i don't 

and i tried in other forms but vba not running

Comment: Are other macros running ? Are macro enabled in that db? Which version of Access ?

Comment: yes other macros running .. access 2007

Comment: i try this code in new database without any macro it works .. what can i do to make it work on my database even the macros running

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Option Access --> Centre de gestion de la confidentialité --> paramètres du Centre de gestion de la confidentialité --> paramètres des marcos --> (coché le dernier choix) activer toutes les macros ...
et OK 
voilà la réponse

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that `On Click` property of Commande15 button contains `[Event Procedure]` value

Comment: Then check database security - you should see at startup the yellow stripe with warning about not trusted application and disabling macroses in this case

Comment: where can i check database security in access 2007 .
can you explain more please

Comment: The easiest way is to add the directory, which contains your database to trusted location, see for instance here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-7ee1cdc2-483e-4cbb-bcb3-4e7c67147fb4

Comment: As I see, other macroses are working, in this case it looks like your database  corrupted. Try to copy all objects from your database to new database file